# Array Map in JS can't catch undefined

Tags: javascript, dictionary, null, undefined

I'm building a list based on data from an API.
From the said API, I get an array of Objects, for some reason the first and last have undefined values.
Using the code below I'm trying to catch the undefined values, but I can't seem to handle it.
the values go through no matter what.

```
  results.map(result => {
      var distance = result.distance;
      if(distance !== undefined || distance !== 'undefined' || distance !== "undefined" || distance !== null){
        console.log(distance, typeof distance);
        var list_button = document.createElement('button', 'button');
        list_button.setAttribute('class', 'list_button');
        list_button.innerText = `${result.title} -- ${distance}`;
        listParent.appendChild(list_button);
      }else{
        console.log('distance is undefined');
    }
    });
```

Comment: print result to figure out what is the object there

Comment: Either one of `distance !== undefined` and `distance !== 'undefined'` is _always_ true. `distance ` is either not `undefined` or not a string. And the logical OR (`||`) returns `true` if either side is `true`. Is the logical AND (`&&`) instead.

Comment: @Ivar I've console logged the result, and the first result is undefined, not the string. It should catch it as the code is. If I change to the & operator, it'll definitely miss it

Comment: No: Because you are checking whether they are *not* undefined. So, the condition will never be false! (Also, `'undefined'` and `"undefined"` are the same string by the way.)

Comment: "if the apple is NOT red OR the apple is NOT green, then I'll eat it" - you'll eat any apple now. Because if it's red, then "NOT red" will be false, but "NOT green" will be true since red isn't green, and you are combining with OR, so it's enough that one of 
 those things was true. Same if it's green. Or any other color. If, however, you'd say "if the apple is NOT red AND the apple is NOT green", then it'll match anything that's neither red nor green (yellow for example).

Comment: @PastaMouse If `distance` is `undefined` then it is not `'undefined'` (string) right? So that would mean that `distance !== undefined` would be `false` and `distance !== 'undefined'` would be `true`. And `false || true` is `true` so it will enter your if-statement. But that being said what are you trying to do in your map? A map maps every element in an array to a different element. The element it becomes is the element that is returned by the callback, but you don't return anything at all there.

Comment: @Ivar CherryDT -- thanks, I've thought about it and changed my code